# Adobe Reader cannot correctly read out loud table in tagged document

Tags: accessibility, adobe-reader

I'm trying to create accessible table which Adobe Reader pronounce 'correctly'. It means that before pronouncing contents of the cell it speaks name of the header of the current column (or row). (It explained better at the first link below).

For this I've created single-page document with a table like this.

```
+------+-----+-----+
| Name | Sex | Age |
+------+-----+-----+
|Antony|Male |  26 |
+------+-----+-----+
|Robert|Male |  36 |
+------+-----+-----+
```

Then with "Touch Up Reading Order" tool I've changed properties of each cell to create references to header cells.

It expected to pronounce:
"Name. Antony. Sex. Male. Age. Twenty six. Name. Robert. Sex. Male. Age. Thirty six."
But it read table row by row.

Maybe I didn't enable something?

I've used this links to prepare document:

http://teachingcommons.cdl.edu/access/docs_multi/pdf_vid_tut/repair_docs/identifying/identifying_table_headers.shtml (Associating Data Cells to Row and Column Headers)

http://www.the508compliantpdf.com/creating_complex_tables_in_indesign_and_acrobat/